# Factorial calculator return INF value as result

Tags: php

The following function return `INF` for result. So I guess that because the number getting too big but how can I fix it?

```
class Factoriel {

public function calculate() {
    if(func_num_args() != 1)
        throw new Exception ("Invalid arguments count for method calculate!");

    if(($n = (int)func_get_arg(0)) <= 0)
        throw new Exception ("Invalid argument supplied for method calculate!");

    $result = 1;
    foreach(range(1, $n) as $current)
        $result = $this->multiply ($result, $current);

    return $result;
}
private function multiply($left, $right) {
    return $left * $right;
   }
}

$factoriel = new Factoriel();

echo $factoriel->calculate(1500);
```

Comment: Factorial of `1500`? That would be rrreeeeally big number. And yes - it won't be possible to use standard `double` for it. You may try with [`bc_math`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) - but I can't imagine use-case for such numbers.

Comment: Thank's for your replay. So what is the maximum number that `php` can calculate in this case.?

Comment: @Goro you can try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [bcmul](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) function for multiplication like

```
return bcmul("$left","$right");
```

instead of

```
return $left * $right;
```

See **[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/OdQWQ)** of fact(500);

Answer (score 2):

Factorial of 1500 is too big for PHP to calculate, that's why you are getting INF, meaning an infinite number. Have a read at http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-infinite.php

Comment: I see.. So there is no way to calculate this via php?

Comment: There are few ways. There are two libraries in PHP to work with big numbers. http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php  and  http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php  read introduction of each and see which one suits your needs and matches your program flow. Seems GNU MP is the one you need. And if all fails you can write your own function to do the job treating numbers and result as a string, probably using arrays, or linked-lists.

Comment: I just tried also with `gmp` -> `return gmp_mul($left, $right);` but the result is `Resource id #1502`. BC seems to work ok for now.

Comment: My apologies, I don't really know which one is better, I always match the flow of my algorithm and see which one fits better, and I rarely use them.